# How to insert values to a database in Class B from a JTextField input that is in Class A

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I am making a Online  food ordering system for a project but i m still new to java. I have two classes. Signin.java and other is mextable.java. I am trying to access a textfield (part of signin.java), read *that* value from Mextable.java and insert that value into a table inside MexTable.java.

I am able to read the value from the `JTextField` in signin.java. I am also able to take that data and insert it to a table `login` in the same class, signin.java.

So my question is exactly **how do I do the same in a different class? Means  read and insert the username (that was entered in`JTextField` in signin.java) into table `orders`(which is part of the Mextable.java)?**

[image: Signin.java Login page Screenshot]

[image: ORder Table from MExTable.java]

**Signin.java code**(i have added just the main lines of the code):

```
     public class signin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

      Connection conn;

      OracleResultSet rs = null; 
        OraclePreparedStatement pst;

  public signin() {
    initComponents();

    connect();
}
  public void connect()
  {
     // connection with database
      }
 private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    

    protected static javax.swing.JTexfield userTF;

    try{

    String pass = passTF.getText().trim();
    String user = userTF.getText().trim();
    String sql = "select uname,pass"
            + " from login "
            + "where uname = '"+user+"' "
            + "AND pass = '"+pass+"'";
   pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = (OracleResultSet) pst.executeQuery(sql);

      // remaining code
   }

      //catch block

   }
```

**Mextable.java:**

accessing the component value of the userTF textfield from the Signin.java is apparently not working because that value is not being inserted. Instead of that value, NULL is inserted. Rest of the values in this insert query are inserted in the table `orders`.

```
   private void ConOrd2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try{
     signin l = new signin();
        l.getComponent(0).getName();
        int rows = jTable23.getRowCount();
          String user4 = l.userTF.getText().trim();
      String sqli = "insert into orders"
            + "(o_id,item_id, order_name, uname)"
            + " values (ord_seq.nextval,?,?,'"+user4+"')"; 

          //o_id,item_id,order_name is inserted and uname value is added as       
   //Null instead of the username value in the JTextfield in the Signin page.

        pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sqli);
        for(int row =0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            String item2= (String)jTable23.getValueAt(row, 0);
            String fooname2= (String)jTable23.getValueAt(row, 1);
            pst.setString(1, item2);
            pst.setString(2, fooname2);
            pst.execute();
        }
        pst.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}                               
       }
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. What you're asking for? Where is your code for Signin.java? How could we help you without it, since you complain this class is not working?

Comment: I have added the code already. The code for Signin.java is the first section of the code block. I said accessing the value is not working and that value is not being inserted. The rest is. The class is working fine. There is no issue there. Just the input `JTexfield` value(from Signin.java) is not being inserted into a table that is in another class named MexTable.java.

Comment: Sir, I have made it bold now so its easily distinguishable

Comment: What is the question ?How to retrieve data from a `JTextField` ? How to pass a variable from class A to class B ? How to write it to a database ? Could you post an [MCVE] with one concise question ?

Comment: i have made edit. I added a screenshot for a better idea and i made my question into a single form . My question is in bold.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can analys  from the question the flow goes from signin to mextable. And everyuser will have the username.in that case you can make the field JTextField as public  static and use that field in the mextable class.

In signin class

Public static JTextField val ;

And to access in mextable use

Class name.variablename;

Signin.val;

Comment: i made it into public static  `JTextField` userTF; and then in mextable i accessed it normally like singin l = new singin(); then   String sqli = "insert into orders"
                + "(o_id,item_id, order_name, uname)"
                + " values (ord_seq.nextval,?,?,'"+l.userTF.getText().trim();+"')";

Comment: But still the nothing shows up the orders table for the column uname

Comment: You need not create an object for a static field, just use classname.variable name.p please check if the field is getting populated before being accessed by the mextable class

Comment: I made it like singin.userTF.getText(); and i checked the orders table again. Still no luck! :( And the field is not being populated before it gets accessed by mextable.class.

Comment: If it is not getting populated how do you expect to get to mextable .i am assuming that at first you use sign in and there the field must get populated. In order for signing to work and then you can store the value some where in any field and access ir across classes.